# setting a name for a pushed items in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Apologies if this is already answered somewhere as it seems like a common thing, but I couldn't find an answer here or in the documentation so here goes.

I would like to know how to assign a name to a pushed item using Firebase.  Basically I want this result:
"Groups" -> Group Name -> "Members" -> Member Name

But I have got this:
"Groups" -> "-JXEy7nfYGsMkdzsK9km" -> "-JXEw_eoCzj_VgqYkJS8" -> Member Name

*I'm sure that is all the info you need to answer this but just in case more detail is needed I will add some more below.*

---

The following is the code I have got.  Basically it is someone creating a new group and assigning that person to that group.

```
var createGroup = function(){
var newGroup = groupRef.push({
    "Name" : newGroupName.val()
});
var groupID = newGroup.name(); //Gets group name, doesn't take arguments
var owner = groupRef.child(groupID).push({
        "Name" : currentUser
    });
```

As you can see I can get the name of what has been pushed but I can't work out how to set it to something else.

Comment: You'd do well to dig through [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) and get a good primer on how all of this fits together as you're missing some fundamental parts of the API from your toolbox.

Comment: Could you tell me what specifically I am missing?  I looked through the guides quite a lot trying to solve this myself so a bit of direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `push()`, which generates a unique key and child location.

What you want to do is call `set()`, which will add the data at that location.

```
var createGroup = function() {
  var newGroup = groupRef.push({
    "Name" : newGroupName.val()
  });
  var groupID = newGroup.name(); 
  var owner = groupRef.child(groupID).set({ // <-- change to set
    "Name" : currentUser
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize a push wasn't the way to go for that.